# Web Broser Control does not update inner html

Tags: vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a simple Windows Form with a WebBroswer control.
This WebBroswer goes to a page, which always sends the webbrowser to another random site.

For some reason, the webbroswer only grabs the inner html of the initial page and never refreshes the inner html or the document.

I have used both the Refresh and Update functions but none of them make the inner html show the second page, only the initial page.

Comment: Are you sure the second page has been fully loaded? You may need to use an event, or check status, to make sure the page is in place.

Comment: After much effort I found that this was the issue, alongside frames. So, I am now trying to find out how to check that the redirect of the page has finished and then look for the button in one of the inner frames.

Comment: DocumentCompleted() is probably the event. At first fire the URL will be the original so you can disregard that one. Note sure of DocumentComplete() drills down to the iframes...

Comment: Got any code to show?